# C check if array stack its empty or not problem

Tags: c, struct, initialization, stack

I create array stack and 2 fuctions. Fuction push to add something to the stack and fuction isempty to check if the stack are empty but its not work, so where is the mistake.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 10

struct stack
{
    int items[MAX];
    int top;
};

typedef struct stack st;

int isempty(st *s)
{
    if (s->top==-1)
    {
        printf("it's empty");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("it's not empty");
    }
}

void push(st *s)
{
    int newitem;
    printf("Enter item: ");
    scanf("%d",&newitem);
    s->top++;
    s->items[s->top]=newitem;
}

int main()
{
    st *s;
    push(s);
    isempty(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `st *s;` Uninitialised pointer. It is undefined behaviour to access an uninitialised pointer.

Comment: In addition to the pointer you also never initialise the value of `top`. You have a check for `-1` to indicate empty but no where in your code is a `-1` value ever set.

Comment: What is the magic value `-1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `isempty` has a non-void return type. So it must return a value. For example

```
int isempty(st *s)
{
    if (s->top==-1)
    {
        printf("it's empty");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("it's not empty");
    }

    return s->top==-1;
}
```

The second problem is that you did not initialize the pointer to  an object of the structure

```
st *s;
```

There is no need to declare the pointer. You could write

```
st s = { { 0 }, -1 };
```

and call the functions like

```
push( &s );
isempty( &s );
```